# compatibility of bash parameter expansion/string manipulation

Tags: bash, compatibility

I'm writing a `bash` script which uses parameter expansion like these a few times throughout:

```
${pathvariable%/*}
${pathvariable##*/}
```

I'll need to run this script on some boxes which may have older versions of `bash` installed.  I know it works in `bash 4.1+` but I'm wondering how portable it is?

- Is this kind of construction going to fail in older versions of `bash`? If so, which versions?
- Is there a more portable construct I should consider?

Comment: Both constructs are in the POSIX standard, so they're as portable as you are likely to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined in POSIX (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)) so you should be safe.

**EDIT**: In case you are paranoid and don't trust in bash's compliance:

```
$ ./bash --posix
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
2.05a.0(1)-release
$ foo="foo/bar"
$ echo "${foo%/*}"
foo
$ echo "${foo##*/}"
bar
```

`2.05a` was released in ~2001.

Answer (score 2):

This should not fail in any version of bash since its really a korn shell construct.  As long as your sure you will be using bash (any version) your fine.